# how to change header of a data frame with another data frame header?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-csv

I have a data set which looks like this

```
LineItem.organizationId|^|LineItem.lineItemId|^|StatementTypeCode|^|LineItemName|^|LocalLanguageLabel|^|FinancialConceptLocal|^|FinancialConceptGlobal|^|IsDimensional|^|InstrumentId|^|LineItemSequence|^|PhysicalMeasureId|^|FinancialConceptCodeGlobalSecondary|^|IsRangeAllowed|^|IsSegmentedByOrigin|^|SegmentGroupDescription|^|SegmentChildDescription|^|SegmentChildLocalLanguageLabel|^|LocalLanguageLabel.languageId|^|LineItemName.languageId|^|SegmentChildDescription.languageId|^|SegmentChildLocalLanguageLabel.languageId|^|SegmentGroupDescription.languageId|^|SegmentMultipleFundbDescription|^|SegmentMultipleFundbDescription.languageId|^|IsCredit|^|FinancialConceptLocalId|^|FinancialConceptGlobalId|^|FinancialConceptCodeGlobalSecondaryId|^|FFAction|!|
Japan|^|1507101869432|^|4295876606|^|1|^|BAL|^|Cash And Deposits|^|null|^|null|^|ACAE|^|false|^|null|^|null|^|null|^|null|^|false|^|null|^|null|^|null|^|null|^|505126|^|505074|^|null|^|null|^|null|^|null|^|null|^|null|^|null|^|3018759|^|null|^|I|!|
```

And this is how i load data with auto discover schema

```
val df1With_ = df.toDF(df.columns.map(_.replace(".", "_")): _*)
val column_to_keep = df1With_.columns.filter(v => (!v.contains("^") && !v.contains("!") && !v.contains("_c"))).toSeq
val df1result = df1With_.select(column_to_keep.head, column_to_keep.tail: _*)
```

Now i have another data frame on which i do join operation and finally i create a data frame which writes output to csv file .

Final data frame looks like this

```
val dfMainOutputFinal = dfMainOutput.select($"DataPartition", $"StatementTypeCode",concat_ws("|^|", dfMainOutput.schema.fieldNames.filter(_ != "DataPartition").map(c => col(c)): _*).as("concatenated"))

val dfMainOutputFinalWithoutNull = dfMainOutputFinal.withColumn("concatenated", regexp_replace(col("concatenated"), "null", ""))

dfMainOutputFinalWithoutNull.write.partitionBy("DataPartition","StatementTypeCode")
  .format("csv")
  .option("nullValue", "")
  .option("header","true")
  .option("codec", "gzip")
  .save("output")
```

Now in my output file i see my header as only  `concatenated` which is expected .

Now my question is is there anyway to change header of my final output as header of `df1result` data frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the simplest way to solve this would be to rename the `concatenated` column. As the column names already exists in the `column_to_keep` variable, you can simply do:

```
val header = column_to_keep.mkString("|^|")
val dfMainOutputFinalWithoutNull = dfMainOutputFinal
  .withColumn("concatenated", regexp_replace(col("concatenated"), "null", ""))
  .withColumnRenamed("concatenated", header)
```

This will result is an extremely long column name, hence, I wouldn't advice it if it was for something else than saving to a csv.

Comment: Hi Shaido what if i have to `|` at last column only for header  ?

Comment: So my header last column should look like this `FFAction|!|` but currently i am getting like `FFAction|^|!`

Comment: @SUDARSHAN change the `mkString("|^|")` to `mkString("", "|^|", "|")`.

Comment: not getting correct one now getting correct one still getting this `FFAction|^|!|` `|^|` has to be removed from last one i am trying

Comment: @SUDARSHAN try this instead, should probably work for you: val header = column_to_keep.dropRight(1).mkString("", "|^|", "|!|")

Comment: It worked thanks ...Just last thing any recomendation to learn scala syntax from book or source ?

Comment: @SUDARSHAN The first book on Scala I looked at was "Scala for the Impatient", it's good if you want to learn the syntax and already know some Java/C++. You could also look into the "Functional Programming Principles in Scala" course on Coursera.